# How do I get an installed script to ignore PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pip

I know I can get Python to ignore `PYTHONPATH` if I start it with the `-E` flag.

But how do I get a script installed by `pip` to have this flag?

I tried both the "scripts" and the "console_scripts" section of the code and `pip` strips the -E if I put it on the #! line.

Comment: why would you want this? Shouldn't it up for the target system to decide what its paths are?

Comment: I install tools for people, but then they have a PYTHONPATH that includes libraries from another version of Python entirely. So they come back with a stack trace of some function missing from `subprocess` or another system module. I'd rather have the command "just work" than have to tell them to clean their PYTHONPATH. Life is short.

Comment: I see what you mean, but still don't think it should be your problem. All you can do is treat a symptom, and once something changes you need to adjust and treat new symptoms. A clear rule in the docs/your issue tracker and maybe a warning if `PYTHONPATH` was set is what I would do. If people need those paths they should add a `somemodule.pth` file in their site-packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way right now seems to be to put write a scripts that restarts Python if the flag is not included:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
if not sys.flags.ignore_environment:
      import os
      os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, '-E'] + sys.argv)
# Run your actual script here
```

Then in setup.py, put this:

```
setup(..., scripts=['myscript'], ...)
```

Don't use entry_points/console_scripts. This should not be used for public modules, just for internal scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I generally recommend against this sort of trickery. The target system puts paths in place for a reason. If you want to break out of a virtualenv you should simply recommend not installing in a virtualenv in your documentation.

However you can remove the entry from `sys.path`.

```
import sys
import os

sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if p not in [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':')]]
```

Comment: This doesn't really do it and only works if PYTHONPATH is a single path. I install the tools in a virtualenv. I wish the executables I install only used that virtualenv's include paths.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer to work with multiple paths in `PYTHONPATH`