# How do I get my python application to ignore PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py, pythonpath

I have a python application (it is a command line interface application) which is invoked through entry_points/console_scripts of setup.py.

Whenever users have a locally specified PYTHONPATH that includes libraries from another version of Python, the application fails.

I have gone through [How do I get an installed script to ignore PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490935/how-do-i-get-an-installed-script-to-ignore-pythonpath), but it recommends not using console_scripts, which is not possible in my case.

I need a way to ensure that the PYTHONPATH that is locally specified by the user is ignored or removed when the application is launched. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This seems more a problem of educating the users than you fixing it. If someone decides to mess around with their environment, then it's essentially their problem.

Comment: +1 to @Evert. This sounds like a problem that could be mitigated by using a virtualenv. Users should be instructed to create an isolated python environment with the specified version that you want to be used.

Comment: You can always try to wrap things in a shell script that stores the `PYTHONPATH` temporary in another variable, unsets `PYTHONPATH`, runs your script, then (re)sets `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @user2896976 The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable remains set and visible inside a virtualenv, so it doesn't really help the current situation.

Comment: Does the env var not point to the python executable created by the virtualenv? "[...] includes libraries from another version of Python, the application fails." If you create a virtualenv with the python version you want, it should update the env var, no? That's the whole point of the venv

Comment: @user2896976 It will point to another Python executable, but that Python executable will *also* see the `PYTHONPATH` envvar. Easiest to confirm is to try it out: set a `PYTHONPATH`, create and start a virtualenv, start `python` and look at `sys.path` in the interpreter. It'll include the `PYTHONPATH` value, notably near the front of the list.

Comment: Thank you @Evert and user2896976. I have informed the users to remove/unset any locally set PYTHONPATH environment variable before launching the application, but this is a persistent ask by them that the application should be able to ignore the set PYTHONPATH. Hence, I am looking for options on how to do it. The application runs inside the virtualenv, but when the PYTHONPATH is locally set incorrect versions of libraries get accessed/imported and the application fails to load.

Comment: If you are invoking the app just through the terminal e.g. `python app.py` then you could simply have a script that handles this for you. [Bash example](https://pastebin.com/vh3as7v9)

Comment: @user2896976 that script doesn't restore `PYTHONPATH` when finished; see also my second comment.

Comment: @Evert It doesn't need to. `export` and `unset` are only applied to the local scope of a script **unless** you invoke the script with `source` or `.` Try setting an env var in the terminal, invoking a script that calls `unset`, and then checking the value of the var after the script is finished.

Comment: @user2896976.. no my application is a complete package and is not invoked as python app.py. The main function of the application is invoked through the console_script of the entry_point of setup.py